Openbox hide cursor
I'm using openbox on Raspberry Pi to autostart my GUI application. The autostart works fine, but before the app launches there's a cursor visible in the middle of the screen. Is there any way to hide it? I have tried:
startx -- -nocursor (the main app doesn't start)
unclutter (when I move the cursor it appears for a predefined short time, but still)
I installed custom transparent cursors generated with xcursorgen, they appear under lxappearance, but there are no icon in the preview window and it doesn't work.
